# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Salesforce's [second moderator election](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Adrian Larson]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6298592314654720/0).

Comment: Congratulations @adrian .You deserve it :) .Keep up the great work :)

Comment: Congrats @adrianlarson. Well deserved! I know you'll do a great job!

Comment: Congratulations @adrian! :)

Comment: Congratulations @Adrian Larson....

Comment: Congratulation @Adrian Larson :)

Comment: Congratulations @AdrianLarson. You deserve this !

Comment: Congrats @AdrianLarson - well deserved! Keep up  your fantastic work on SFSE!

Comment: @adrianlarson Congrats!!!

Comment: Congrats bud! Keep it up!

Comment: Congratulation @Adrian Larson

Comment: Congratulation @Adrian , Excited to seeing you on board :)

Comment: Congratulations, very well deserved!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: You are an inspiration to us all!

Comment: Congrats @adrian, well deserved.

Answer (score 39):

Well thank you everyone! I am excited to continue my commitment to making our corner of the Internet one of the best places to gain knowledge about the Salesforce platform. I look forward to serving and am proud of the trust you place in me. Happy 2017!

Comment: Three cheers for our new benevolent overlord!

Comment: Congratulations Adrian, you have the power. Remember what Spiderman's uncle said, because I can't. But it's inspirational as!

Comment: Congrats on your new ♦! You totally deserve it!

Comment: Cheer's buddy. You already were moderator in the eyes of many SE members.

Comment: Congratulations!! @AdrianLarson All the very best. (y)

Comment: Glad to have you on the team!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats Adrian!

Comment: Congratulations @Adrian!!

Comment: congrats @Adrian!

Comment: Ha ha, been tied up for the last few days and was surprised when there weren't any flags earlier... guess I know why now :) Congrats bud!

Answer (score 0):

Congrats @Adrian You deserve it :)